# how to make an application which expire at particular time in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I am creating an application which will expire after some particular time limit. means user can't access it's methods and user should buy or register it's downloaded application. user can open application but after some time limit user can't use application functionality.
Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think apple will like this

Comment: It's not allowed. It would be rejected.

Comment: This won't be allowed for the app store, but if you're doing this for beta test an app using ad-hoc distribution or for in internal Enterprise app, this is a reasonable question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all:

Apple would not reject your application if you use any of the function which is not listed in its private API.

So if you want to block your application after a specific time, You can implement it logically.

For this Once your application is downloaded in a device, Store the current time & date in Your Application Preferences (User Defaults). Although in this option If user will remove the application & re-install the application the preferences will reset.

So There are various places which is not removed till the iOS device is not reset (Like Keychain). Apple provides methods to store Data in keychain.

Next is what you have to do is Each time when user open your application, You need to check the current time with the Stored time in App.

If it validates your limit, You can Let user use the application or Throw an Alert & Do whatever action you want.

I hope it may helpful for you.

Comment: First line is blatantly false. Apple has a number of rules which guide their acceptance or rejection of applications; the usage of private APIs is just one of them.

Comment: Expiring apps are prohibited by the iOS Review Guidelines, section 2.9: "Apps that are 'beta', 'demo', 'trial', or 'test' versions will be rejected."

Comment: That is for application beta version or demo version or trial version. Not for full version whose functionality will not work after a particular time. If user dont want to use a function in the application after a particular point of time, Then Its Ok. developer can put his logic to implement it. I dont think anything bad into it logically & also apple would not think so..

Answer (score 1):

I've done this by using a build script which creates a file with a timestamp every time I compile. The file is part of the build target and gets deployed with the app. When the app runs, code checks the timestamp on the file and if to much time has past the app throws up an alert page and does nothing else.

**Now the disclaimer**. I use this system with development versions of enterprise applications. This prevents old development versions from cluttering up and prevent people from getting old development versions and thinking they are recent. I would never think of using this system on production deployed applications.

**Edit**: Per request I'm added the code and script I use. It's not great, but it works. If anyone would like to improve on it I'd be happy to see better versions. I have the script set to run right before the "Compile Sources" task

```
builddate=`date`

# if BuildDateString doesn't exist, add it
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :BuildDateString string $builddate" "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$INFOPLIST_PATH"
# and if BuildDateString already existed, update it
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :BuildDateString $builddate" "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$INFOPLIST_PATH"
```

The Objective-C code I use exists in static library of code which I tend to use across a fair number of projects. It also includes a simple `UIViewController` called `TSExpiredViewController` to display an expired message if needed.

```
+ (void)expireAppAfterOneWeek {
    [self expireAppAfter:604800];
}

+ (void)expireAppAfter:(NSTimeInterval)secondsAfterBuilds {
    id<UIApplicationDelegate> appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    NSString *buildDateString = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"BuildDateString"];
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateFormat = @"EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss zz yyyy";
    NSDate *buildDate = [df dateFromString:buildDateString];

    if (-[buildDate timeIntervalSinceNow] > secondsAfterBuilds) {
        appDelegate.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        TSExpiredViewController *viewController = [[TSExpiredViewController alloc] init];
        appDelegate.window.rootViewController = viewController;
        [appDelegate.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
}
```